# My regular expression is failing when trying to extract an HTML attribute

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a value from an HTML page that has the name "this"
ex:

```
name="this" value="XXXX-XXX-xxxxx-xxxxx"
```

I tried to use

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("name=\"this\" value=\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher match = pat.matcher(sb);
        if(match.matches())
            return match.group();
```

But nothing returned. What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Either `find` or `matches("(?s)^.*name=\"this\" value=\"(.*?)\".*$");` where `(?s)` (DOTALL) accepts newlines for the dot (.). **matches() is for a matching of the entire text.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Joop said; use "find":

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("name=\"this\" value=\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher match = pat.matcher(sb);
if(match.find())
    return match.group(1);
```

Also note that you'll want to retrieve "group(1)", since just group() returns the entire pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider more conditions , like

```
name = "this" id = "something" value = 'xxx'
```

Then your pattern wouldn't meet the requirements such as space between "name" and "=" 'xxx' and string between attribute "name" and attribute "value", so I think the pattern should be like the following form:

```
private final String matchString = "name\\s*=\\s*(?:\"this\")|(?:'this')" +
                                    ".*?" +
                                    "value\\s*=\\s*" +
                                    "(?:\"([^\"]*)\") |(?: '([^']*)')";
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(matchString,Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.COMMENTS); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

    while(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

At the same time , the tip from up floor is needed!